# Use MySQL instead of MondoDB along with Node.js in MEAN structured framework

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mean-stack

For a single page application or considering the speed of an application we generally switch to MEAN. But my question is that do I get the same speed and performance when I use Mysql as a database instead of document database like MongoDB?

Considering the fact that bulk insert or update operations are not required in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the Mysql is RDMBS which has strong table schema where as Mongodb is a collection based database which is not have strong schema(NoSQL).

Speed wise its difficult to judge entirely if mysql will be better or mongodb directly without looking at schema. However, if properly indexed, the performance can be optimised for any of those.

However to choose between those 2, might want to check following parameters :

- If you application schema is defined(mysql is good) or its a ver loosely bound structure and can change from document(record) to document(Mongodb is good)?
- Is you applications is divided into different tables like mapping tables, pivot tables to have many primary-foreign key relationships? Then mysqls a good choice, if not too many joins Mongodb is good. Mongodb can be used to join but a simple join query in mysql might be a long nested $lookup json query in mongodb aggregate.
- Mongodb query syntax is really intuitive and more inclined to javascript-like syntax. So development-wise its easy to manage and rework.
- If you are having text-searches then mongodb has good set of $text index which has tokenisation and analysers. Its difficult to achieve comparatively in mysql.
- Data locality is present in mongodb nore reliably than mysql.
- Mongodb has autosharding as mentioned in their documentation for high availability which you will need to configure by your own in mysql.
- Node packages like mongoose would also give you ORM like models to query into mongodb if you want to use mongo but still want the model helper functions to query.

Comment: Thanks @Blastfreak for providing the information by. You really made a clear distinction between Mysql and MongoDB on different related factors and conditions.
Much appreciated points were Lookups and Tokenization.

Comment: Can you explain in brief about the Lookup's in MongoDB and its related query. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: $lookup is nothing but a join in mongodb.If you have 4 tables in mysql : users, roles , pivot table user_role and products table. It user-role has many to many relationship. Now if you want to get all products of a user which has a role of seller, doing this mysql is straightforward, however doing this in mongodb is quite complex. So we use arrays instead of pivot table. So in mongidb rather than having pivot table, i will have an array of roles for every user.  This will make the lookup easy. So both have different use cases and structure to implement same stuff.

Comment: Thanks Blastfreak for quoting an example with explanation. So what if want to get data from 2 collections having a common key for them to join in MongoDB. Is this possible or I have to play the same role of including pivot table as an array instead in the same collection.